# Создание объектов в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь начать изучать `Spring`. Но не могу понять как создать элементарный объект, передав в конструктор значения.

Вот класс `People`, который имеет несколько полей. Я его помечаю аннотацией `@Component`, чтобы из него дальше создать бин.

```
@Component
public class People {
    private int id;
    private String fam;
    private String im;
    private String ot;
    private Date bdate;
    private String note;

    public People() {
    }

    public People(String fam, String im, String ot, Date bdate, String note) {
        this.fam = fam;
        this.im = im;
        this.ot = ot;
        this.bdate = bdate;
        this.note = note;
    }

    public People(String fam, String im, String ot) {
        this.fam = fam;
        this.im = im;
        this.ot = ot;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFam() {
        return fam;
    }

    public void setFam(String fam) {
        this.fam = fam;
    }

    public String getIm() {
        return im;
    }

    public void setIm(String im) {
        this.im = im;
    }

    public String getOt() {
        return ot;
    }

    public void setOt(String ot) {
        this.ot = ot;
    }

    public Date getBdate() {
        return bdate;
    }

    public void setBdate(Date bdate) {
        this.bdate = bdate;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }
}
```

Как в классе `MainApp` я могу создать объект `People` передав в конструктор `People(String fam, String im, String ot)` значения?

Мой класс MainApp

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test.entities");

        People people1 = context.getBean(People.class);

        System.out.println(people1.getFam());

    }
}
```

Создаю дополнительный класс MyConfig

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public People getPeopleAndrew() {
        return new People("Test", "Andrew", "Testovich");
    }

    @Bean
    public People getPeopleIgor() {
        return new People("Test", "Igor", "Testovich");
    }

}
```

Метод в MainApp

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);

        People people1 = context.getBean(People.class);
        System.out.println(people1.getFam());

        People people2 = context.getBean(People.class);
        System.out.println(people2.getFam());

    }
}
```

Тут получается что спринг нашел два одинаковых бина как я понимаю и не знает какой из них создать. Как тут например получить бин getPeopleIgor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**По 1 вопросу**:

> Как в классе MainApp я могу создать объект People передав в
> конструктор People(String fam, String im, String ot) значения?

Да можете, только нужно изменить MyConfig

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public People getConsrtuctedUser(String fam, String im, String ot) {
        return new People(String fam, String im, String ot);
    }
}
```

**@Scope(value = "prototype")** - с помощью данного вида scope, спринг не будет инициализировать бин на старте, а будет создавать только при вызове(в главном классе MyApp).

B MainApp вызываете:

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);

        People people = context.getBean(People.class, "fam", "asda", "asdasd");
        System.out.println(people1.getFam());

    }
}
```

**По поводу 2 вопроса:**

> Тут получается что спринг нашел два одинаковых бина как я понимаю и не
> знает какой из них создать. Как тут например получить бин
> getPeopleIgor?

Берем ваш конфиг(не меняем):

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public People getPeopleAndrew() {
        return new People("Test", "Andrew", "Testovich");
    }

    @Bean
    public People getPeopleIgor() {
        return new People("Test", "Igor", "Testovich");
    }

}
```

Если вы явно не указываете название бина(*Например @Bean("customBeanName")*), то спринг сам по умолчанию называет его по названию метода(*для Andrew это будет бин с названием "getPeopleAndrew", а для Igor - "getPeopleIgor"*).

**MainApp:**

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test.entities");

        People peopleAndrew = context.getBean(People.class, "getPeopleAndrew");
        People peopleIgor = context.getBean(People.class, "getPeopleIgor");


    }
}
```

Comment: Поняла, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Как и обычно создают экземпляры класса.

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("test.entities");

        People people1 = new People("fam", "asda", "asdasd");

        System.out.println(people1.getFam());

    }
}
```

дам кусочек [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/139736/)

> Аннотации представляют из себя дескрипторы, включаемые в текст
> программы, и используются для хранения метаданных программного кода,
> необходимых на разных этапах жизненного цикла программы. Информация,
> хранимая в аннотациях, может использоваться соответствующими
> обработчиками для создания необходимых вспомогательных файлов или для
> маркировки классов, полей и т.д.

Comment: А какой тогда смысл помечать класс People аннотацией @Component?

Comment: Ну это для фреймворка. https://habr.com/ru/post/350682/

Comment: Я знаю что такое аннотации и для чего их используют. Мне хотелось бы понять можно ли как-то иначе создать объект People, используя spring? В том примере что вы привели для создания объекта спринг не используется. Например тут https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/477-spring-dlja-lenivihkh-osnovih-bazovihe-koncepcii-i-primerih-s-kodom-chastjh-2 описано как создавать бины, но если нужно что-то передать в конструктор что делать как спринг тут использовать?

Comment: Или же нужно использовать аннотацию @Bean и в методе создавать нужный бин и нужными значениями в конструкторе?

Comment: Создала класс MyConfig с методами @Bean("andrew") и @Bean("igor"). А в MainApp People people1 = context.getBean("andrew", People.class); Правильно ли так делать?

Comment: Вы ведь по инструкции делаете. Она не моя коментарии излишне

Comment: Я по ней не делаю) я статью просто прочитала и теперь пытаюсь понять как создать класс People и создавать несколько разных объектов этого класса используя спринг.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470039/initialize-pojo-object-using-spring

Comment: Спринг, как и любой IoC, нужен не для того, чтобы за вас создавать все объекты, а чтобы инжектить зависимости